# Objects in database cleaned up after debugging

Tags: api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I created a web API following this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Every time I start debugging, all objects are deleted from the database.
Is there any way to keep them in each debugging?

Current:

1. Start debugging.
2. Send a GET request. Response body is empty. Objects created before current debugging are all cleaned up.
3. Send a POST request.
4. Send a GET request. Response body only contains the object created in step3.
5. Stop debugging and go back to step 1.

Expected:

1. Start debugging
2. Send a GET request. Response body contains objects created before current debugging.
3. Send a POST request.
4. Send a GET request. Response body contains objects created before and during current debugging.
5. Stop debugging and go back to step 1

Comment: The link you have attached uses an in-memory database. So, when you are application is stopped, everything will be wiped out. If you need to persist data, you need to use _real_ database like SQL Server, etc

Comment: Thank you, I created another project with a SQL server and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample uses an InMemory DB, that means that the data is only stored in process memory. and process memory will always be lost when the process ends. So to get around this you will have to use a persisted DB provider!

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it is working with an SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to use database:

1.From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console (PMC).

In the PMC, run the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

2.Create a TodoContext in Data folder:

```
public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
```

3.startup.cs/ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TodoContext")));
```

4.appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "TodoContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TodoContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

5.Sacffold like this(use xxxProjectName.Data.TodoContext):
[image]

6.Initial migration:

From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console (PMC).

In the PMC, enter the following commands:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

7.Then your data will be save in database:
[image]